# how to access multiple google drives from colab?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I have 2 files spread over 2 google drives and I want to access the 2 from google colab

I use this code to access to a google drive

```
#Mount Google Drive as folder
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)
```

but when I run again it tells me that the disk is already mounted

how do I upload another disk from another google drive?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pydrive to connect to another drive. But you need to use its API. Cannot just mount.